# Change beamer covered colour to match background

Tags: beamer

I've set `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` so that the covered elements in beamer are transparent. However, I've also set a background colour different from white, and it seems that the `transparent` setting will mix the hidden elements with white and not with the background colour. Is it possible to change the colour of hidden text such that hidden items are mixed with the background colour and not white?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background colour of the font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamercolor{normal font}{parent=background canvas}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamercolor{normal font}}

\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=structure.fg!40!background canvas.bg,bg=background canvas.bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]